# Efficient and effective pagination in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pagination

I know this question has been answered many times. 
In fact if you refer to http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/ppc2009/PPC2009_mysql_pagination.pdf 
you get the answer.

However I have a doubt about this common approach as follows.

If you refer to slide 18, consider the following sequence of events:

1. client fetches  "first page"
2. a post with ID=19 exists in the "third page" , and its thumb_up count increases to 98, thereby pushing it to "first page"
3. client fetches "second page"

The client will then miss the post ID=19.  I'm doing a mobile app where the items are cached on the client's side (imagine an infinite scrolling list).  If the cache is not updated regularly, then this post will be missed for some time!

Any smart way to ensure the client never misses any items, especially in a situation where the client is fetching items that may be updated concurrently by other users?

I thought of imposing a unique "updated timestamp" for each item in the table, as a solution  . However,  this would need some form of serialization to maintain the uniqueness of the timestamp, and wouldn't perform so well for a large number of updates. We also need to ensure the timestamp is monotically increasing, otherwise items may be missed as well.

Comment: eBay has this very issue, if you sort by "ending soonest" - by the time you've browsed the imminent closing, and move the next page, a gap may have been created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IndexedDB of browser, or WebSQL. Go with Indexed DB and dump all the data there (maybe asynchronously), for whichever requests you've already sent.

Comment: I can share a sample for IndexedDB, if you like.